# Setting up MySQL and Apache for RESTful webservices

Tags: java, android, ios, mysql, apache

Can anybody point me in the right direction for instructions on setting up the following items on a Windows development PC?

1. Setup a MySQL database.
2. Setup an Apache webserver, a framework plus an IDE so that I can write RESTful APIs using Java and JSON.

I am using this to write a native Android and IOS mobile app that will store and retrieve data from the MySql database using the RESTful APIs on the Apache web server.

I have searched through several tech books, Google and Stack Overflow but cannot find anything that contains the above specific items. Within Stack Overflow, the following two links proved useful but do not give the specific items that I need. [Android - Ruby on Rails - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029001/android-ruby-on-rails-mysql) AND [Best practice selecting database for mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540459/best-practice-selecting-database-for-mobile-app)

Comment: I too want to implement the same. Have you got any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to develop RESTful APIs using a Windows development PC, you could consider some of the available software bundles like XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), which include an Apache distribution containing MariaDB (successor of MySQL, you can work with MariaDB as you would in MySQL), PHP (server-side language), and Perl (not neccesary) in a single Windows installer. Then, once you install it, you will have a complete web development environment up and running.

Then, considering that you develop your APIs using PHP as the server-side programming language (which I strongly recommend you as it is the most widely used language for this purpose), several additional decisions have to be taken, in terms of deciding about:

- The IDE to develop in. When working with PHP, I recommend you PHPStorm IDE (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm). The best in my humble opinion. However, quite complex and not very easy, but it completely worths learning.
- The PHP framework. Unless you want to manually program your APIs (completely madness), you will have to use one of the many available PHP frameworks. In this case, I recommend you Laravel Framework (http://laravel.com). As far I have seen and worked, the best present and future option concerning PHP development. You could then install some RESTful API specific package in top of Laravel to speed up the development, like Dingo/API (https://github.com/dingo/api).

I insist this is just my recommendation, but you have to know that behind all that languages and frameworks there is a quite long and hard learning curve.

Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1) To install MySQL on Windows refer to [this official MySQL guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html).
You will need to download and then extract the zip file (I would recommend the Community Edition). You will have all the details you need in the link above. Note that the .msi installer for Windows is no longer available for newer versions of MySQL.

2) Since you are going to use Java, you do not need the Apache web server (httpd) but you need **Apache Tomcat** as a servlet container (or other alternatives like Glassfish, JBoss as full Java EE application servers).

For building RESTful Web APIs in Java, **Jersey** is very good option (https://jersey.java.net).

Finally, as an IDE you can use anything, the most popular being Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA.